# For $x\in X$ Prove $C(x)$ is a connected maximal in $X$

Tags: general-topology

For $x\in X$ Prove $C(x)$ is a connected maximal set in $X$

I don't understand the definition of connected maximal set very clear and i don't know how start this exercise, can someone help me with a hint?

Comment: Well, what is $C(x)$?

Comment: is the Connected components @Randall

Comment: So then the connected maximality isn't the definition?

Comment: My definition of connected component $C(x)$ is the union of the all subset connected contain $x$ n@Randall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If maximality is not the definition, then probably the definition is

$$C(x) = \bigcup \{ C \subseteq X: x \in C, C \text{ connected}\}$$

This is a connected set (which contains $x$), as a union of connected sets that all intersect (in $x$). The union is non-void as $C= \{x\}$ is always part of  that union.

And if $C$ is any connected set that contains $x$ then it is **by definition** one of the sets in the union that comprises $C(x)$ and so trivially $C \subseteq C(x)$, and so if $D$ is connected and $C(x) \subseteq D$, we know $x \in D$ so $D \subseteq C(x)$ by the above and hence $C(x) = D$.

($m$ is a maximal element in a partially ordered set $(P, \le)$ iff

$$\forall p \in P: p \ge m \implies p=m$$ and we have shown that a component is a maximal element in the set of all connected subsets of $X$ ordered by $ \subseteq$.)

Comment: Excellent thanks for your help very glad

Comment: @Bvss de nada, contento de poder ayudar..